# Redirect to default action on unmatched controller and action in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and various action methods. I have url as:

```
http://localhost:2032/Info/person
```

I have a requirement that if I enter any wrong controller and action in the URL, it should still redirect it to the above given URL.

Example-if I enter `http://localhost:2032/asjjsjdj` or `http://localhost:2032/info/djwsk` it should redirect to `http://localhost:2032/Info/person`

Please let me know how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add on exception handler and redirect from the your `predefined URL` as mentioned below URL:

[How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc)